# Overwriting RouteController settings

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a route controller like so:

```
StudentPageFeeds = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('headers', this.route.name)
  },
  data: function() {
    return Headers.findOne({});
  }  
});
```

And I have a route:

```
this.route('teacher', {
  path: 'teacher/:_id',
  data: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },
  controller: StudentPageFeeds
});
```

When I do this, the route data is not returned. Removing the route controller fixes the issue however. How can I get the data from the route, if I need to keep the route controller?

Comment: And what happens when you remove `data` hook from the `StudentPageFeeds`?

Comment: It also starts working. It's an issue when I define a data function in the route and the route controller. I couldn't find anywhere in the docs discussing if both data functions are called, or if one overrides another.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the `data` handler in both the controller and the route? Otherwise I'd recommend returning something like `{header: Headers.findOne(), user: Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id)}` from the `data` function.

Comment: The controller has quite a few other options that most other routes need, so I'd like to use it to minimize code duplication. It seems like the data function in the controller takes precedence over the data function in the route.